# Explanation for string behavior ["somestring" "somestring"] being evaluated to ["somestringsomestring"]

Tags: python, string

I'm using python 3.10.4 right now.

I mistakenly wrote `["somestring" "somestring"]` without a `,` separating the strings. Which evaluated to `["somestringsomestring"]` without raising an error (which an error raised was my expectation).

And it seems like it was like that for previous versions.

How should I interpret the process of `"string" "string"` being evaluated to `"stringstring"`?